# Need help creating Student Info Code

Tags: java

I need help creating a Program 
Must Include:
1.  Student
a.  Must have 
i.  Student name (first and last)
ii. Birthdate
iii.    ID #
iv. Grade (Freshman, sophomore, etc.)
v.  Class Schedule (an array?)
vi. 3 constructors of your choice (must include a default)
vii.    Getter and Setter methods for all instance variables
1.  This means that you have at least 2 methods for each instance variable in order to be able to get and set those variables.
2.  The methods will be public, so that they can be used outside the class, and the instance variables will be private, so that they are not broken by the users of your class.
viii.   Proper documentation for all methods

This is what i have so far

```
public class StudentTester
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Student someGuy = new Student();    //This creates a new student using the defalt constructor
    Student someGal = new Student("Amanda","Soh");  //This creates a new student and automatically sets the firt and last name variables

    String justAHolder = someGuy.getFullName();
    String justAnotherHolder = someGal.getFullName();

    System.out.print(someGal.getFullName());
    someGuy.setMonth(11);
    someGal.setMonth(14);
    //If you uncomment the next line and try and compile the program, you will be able to see how it generates an error
    //someGal.grade=12;       //NO, NO, No, grade is supposed to be private!!!!!
}

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Student
 */
public Student()
{
    // initialise instance variables
    fName = "John";
    lName = "Doe";


}

/**
 * This is my second constructor example that students name
 * 
 * @param   fName   This is the input for the first name
 * @param   lName   This is the input for the last name
 */
public Student(String fName, String lName)
{
    this();
    this.fName = fName;
    this.lName = lName;

}

//Here are the Getter Methods
/**
 * This is the getter method to get the full name
 * 
 * @return  This returns the first and last name as a single String
 */
public String getFullName()
{
    return fName+" "+lName;
}

//Here are the Setter Methods
/**
 * This is the method to set the month of the students birthday
 * 
 * @param   newMonth    The new month to set the birthdate with
 */
public void setMonth(int newMonth)
{
    if(newMonth>0 && newMonth<13)
    {
        bDayMonth = newMonth;
    }else
    {
        System.out.println("No one is born in Octovember!");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I see your code, but I can't find a question.

Answer (score 0):

Your Student class :

```
package com.test;

public class Student {

    public Student() {
        firstName = "John";
        lastName = "Doe";
        birthDate = "05/11/1990";
    }

    public Student(String fName, String lName, String dob, String sGrade,
            String[] classSchedule) {
        firstName = fName;
        lastName = lName;
        birthDate = dob;
        grade = sGrade;
        schedule = classSchedule;
    }

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String birthDate;

    private String grade;

    private String[] schedule;

    /**
     * @return the firstName
     */
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    /**
     * @param firstName
     *            the firstName to set
     */
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the lastName
     */
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    /**
     * @param lastName
     *            the lastName to set
     */
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the birthDate
     */
    public String getBirthDate() {
        return birthDate;
    }

    /**
     * @param birthDate
     *            the birthDate to set
     */
    public void setBirthDate(String birthDate) {
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    /**
     * @return the grade
     */
    public String getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    /**
     * @param grade
     *            the grade to set
     */
    public void setGrade(String grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    /**
     * @return the schedule
     */
    public String[] getSchedule() {
        return schedule;
    }

    /**
     * @param schedule
     *            the schedule to set
     */
    public void setSchedule(String[] schedule) {
        this.schedule = schedule;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
}
```

Then the tester class:

```
package com.test;

public class StudentTester {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student st1 = new Student(); // This creates a new student using the
                                        // defalt constructor
        String[] sch = { "Math 10.30", "Physics 14.00" };
        Student st2 = new Student("Amanda", "Soh", "10/12/1990", "Freshman",
                sch);// This creates a new student and automatically sets all
                        // attributes
        System.out.println("First Student is: " + st1.getFullName());
        System.out.println("Details of 2nd student: " + st2.getFullName() + " "
                + st2.getBirthDate() + " " + st2.getGrade() + " "
                + st2.getSchedule()[0] + " " + st2.getSchedule()[1]);
    }

}
```